# Is it possible to Print expressions in reverse order?

Tags: front-end, customization, output, debugging, printing

Let's say I'm debugging a program step by step and want to `Print` some expressions ([using ShowIt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270643/884752), for example).

Is there a way to output the result of `Print` on top of already printed expressions instead of at the bottom?

Comment: Related: "[Strange behavior of Print, Do, and merged output cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182550/280)."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is admittedly messy, but something along these lines might work:

```
insertBelowEvaluationCell[expr_] := 
  (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, EvaluationCell]; 
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes[expr], "Print"]])
```

This function moves the insertion point just below the evaluation cell before inserting the text or expression to be printed.

Let's test it:

```
insertBelowEvaluationCell /@ Range[10]
```

Problems:

- This messes with the insertion point in the notebook which can be modified interactively as well.  Perhaps it's better to write the output into a separate notebook instead.
- It does not work in command line mode (without a front end).
- It's slow (noticeably slower than `Print`).

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it without a front end (unless you are on a terminal interpreting escape sequences, in which case you could output the relevant ones with `Print`, but even then, you might have problems determining how many lines to go up).

Answer (score 9):

This is an arguably even messier solution than Szabolcs', and its performance isn't going to win any awards, but it has some (somewhat dubious) advantages:

1. It allows you to choose whatever target you want for the printing, putting things in an arbitrary notebook, and the output will appear at the current selection in that notebook;
2. After that, printing won't affect the current selection;
3. You can have many different targets for printing;
4. It provides another use for the seemingly useless [`CellTags`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellTags.html) feature!

The function in question creates a dummy cell that will eventually contain the output as a side-effect, and returns a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) that you call like `Print` (more or less; it only takes one argument) in order to direct output to that target cell. The function is here:

```
Pillsy`UpsideDownPrinter[nb_: InputNotebook[]] :=
 With[{
   tag = ToString@FileHash[
      StringToStream@ToString@{NotebookGet@nb, Date[]}]},
  NotebookWrite[nb, Cell["", CellTags -> tag]];
  Function[content,
   Module[{nbExpr = NotebookGet[nb], pos},
     pos = Position[nbExpr, Cell[___, CellTags -> tag, ___]];
     NotebookPut[
      MapAt[
       Replace[#,
         Cell[stuff_, opts___] :>
          Cell[CellGroup[{Cell[content], Cell[stuff]}], opts]] &,
       nbExpr,
       pos],
      nb]];]]
```

First, `NotebookWrite` is used to create a `Cell` in the target notebook with a unique `CellTag` (which is what all the `FileHash` stuff is for), and then we continually modify the target notebook's structure using standard Mathematica structural operations. The stuff with `CellGroup` allows us to effectively create a "linked list" of generated cells in a (probably futile) stab at maintaining some degree of efficiency.

You use it like so:

```
printer = Pillsy`UpsideDownPrinter[];

printer["foo!"]; printer["bar!"]; printer["baz!"];
```

which will give output that looks like

> ```
> "baz!"
> "bar!"
> "foo!"
> ```

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll test it tomorrow. It's a good example of what can be achieved by manipulating notebooks.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the ordering of the output of [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) cells is determined by whether the cells printed have the options [`CellAutoOverwrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellAutoOverwrite) and [`GeneratedCell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratedCell) both set to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False). If so, the cells are printed at the top (in reverse order), otherwise they are printed at the bottom.

In general, it is not easy to control whether the printed cells have these options set to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) using [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print). On the other hand, the mostly equivalent version using [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) does not have this problem. So, using [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) with appropriate options instead of [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print) will print the cells in "reverse" order. However, having these options set to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False) means the next time the input is evaluated, the cells will not be deleted.

This leads to the following function:

```
SetAttributes[ReversePrints, HoldAll];
ReversePrints[expr_] := Block[{Print=myprint, uuid=CreateUUID[]},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        Null,
        expr,
        (* clean up *)
        CurrentValue[Cells[CellTags->uuid], CellAutoOverwrite]=Inherited;
        CurrentValue[Cells[CellTags->uuid], GeneratedCell]=Inherited;
    ]
]

Clear[myprint]
myprint[a__] := CellPrint @ Cell[
    BoxData@MakeBoxes@SequenceForm[a],
    "Print",
    CellTags->uuid,
    GeneratedCell->False,
    CellAutoOverwrite->False
]
```

The function `myprint` "print" cells with the desired options. It also includes a [`CellTags`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellTags) option so that the desired options can be cleared afterwards.

Example:

```
ReversePrints[Do[Print[i], {i, 3}]]
```

> 3
>
> 2
>
> 1

One final note: [`CellPrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint) is noticeably slower than [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print).

Comment: I did not mean to make this a community wiki post, lol.

Comment: I removed it, you can flag things should you have similar accidents.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is robust and efficient solution which exploits the observations described in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182604/280) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) (see also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182570/280)), but is based on another idea.

We change the default style for printed output for `EvaluationCell[]` using the option [`"GeneratedCellStyles"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71346/280). After printing we move the insertion point right after `EvaluationCell[]` (in order to prevent autoscrolling), and then remove the options `GeneratedCell` and `CellAutoOverwrite` from the printed cells:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],
 "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Print" -> {"ReversePrintTag", "Print", GeneratedCell -> False,
      CellAutoOverwrite -> False}}]

Do[Pause[.1]; Print[i], {i, 3}]

SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> "ReversePrintTag"], GeneratedCell] = Inherited;
CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> "ReversePrintTag"], CellAutoOverwrite] = Inherited;
```

> ```
> 3
> 2
> 1
> ```

For someone who extensively dubug differet parts of a program in one Notebook, it may be even more efficient to use unique tag for every evaluation (and the slow `CreateUUID[]` isn't needed: `AbsoluteTime[]` is sufficient for this purpose):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],
 "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Print" -> {"Print", 
     uniqueTag = "ReversePrintAbsoluteTime: " <> IntegerString@IntegerPart@AbsoluteTime[], 
     GeneratedCell -> False, CellAutoOverwrite -> False}}]

Do[Pause[.1]; Print[i], {i, 50}]

SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> uniqueTag], GeneratedCell] = Inherited;
CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> uniqueTag], CellAutoOverwrite] = Inherited;
```

We can package it into a function which allows to reverse printing not only for cells generated by `Print`, but also `Message`, `PrintTemporary`, and for the ordinary outputs. It should be called at the beginning of a `Cell` it is applied to (after finishing evaluation it also takes care of defaulting the options changed for current `Cell`):

```
ClearAll[SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell];
SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell[style_String: "Print"] := 
  SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell[{style}];
SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell[l : {__String}] := 
 With[{uniqueTag = "ReversePrintAbsoluteTime: " <> IntegerString@IntegerPart@AbsoluteTime[], styles = l}, 
  SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], 
   "GeneratedCellStyles" -> 
    Table[style -> {style, uniqueTag, GeneratedCell -> False, 
       CellAutoOverwrite -> False}, {style, styles}], 
   CellEpilog :> (SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
     CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> uniqueTag], GeneratedCell] = Inherited;
     CurrentValue[Cells[CellStyle -> uniqueTag], CellAutoOverwrite] = Inherited;
     SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], 
      "GeneratedCellStyles" -> Table[style -> style, {style, styles}]];
     CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], CellEpilog] = Inherited;)]]
```

An example of use:

```
SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell[];
Do[Pause[.1]; Print[i], {i, 50}]
```

In the same way we can reverse printing of `Message`s:

```
SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell["Message"]
Off[General::stop];
f::msg = "Message `1`.";
Do[Message[f::msg, i], {i, 50}];
```

[image: screenshot]

Set reverse printing for all supported functions:

```
SetReversePrintingForCurrentCell[{"Print", "Message", "Output", "PrintTemporary"}];
Off[General::stop];
f::msg = "Message `1`.";
Do[Print[i]; Message[f::msg, i], {i, 50}];
```

> [image: screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which is even more efficient than my [previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207996/280) and works at least starting from *Mathematica* 8. Significant advantage is that it configures at once reverse printing for all *output* styles defined in the default stylesheet (i.e. `"Output"`, `"Print"`, `"Echo"`, `"PrintTemporary"`, `"Message"` and so on) independently of their names. It can easily be extended for custom/non-default stylesheets. It works by temporary changing `StyleDefinitions` and `CellEpilog` on the Notebook level for the time of evaluation, and then reverting it to the defaults. Working on the Notebook level allows to avoid undesired autoscrolling at the end of evaluation completely (the bug: [CASE:4332680]). Here is the code of the function:

```
ConfigureReversePrintingForCurrentCell[] := AbortProtect[
  (* Causes auto-deletion of pre-existing output under the cell *)
  NotebookDelete@PrintTemporary[""];
  (* Work on the Notebook level auto-reverting to the defaults *)
  SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
   {StyleDefinitions -> 
     Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
       Cell[StyleData[All], GeneratedCell -> False, CellAutoOverwrite -> False]}, 
      StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"],
    CellEpilog :> AbortProtect[
      FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[EvaluationNotebook[]];
      SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"];
      CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEpilog] = Inherited;
      FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[EvaluationNotebook[]];
      ]}]
  ]
```

The function should be called at the beginning of a `Cell` it is applied to.
Here is an example of use:

```
ConfigureReversePrintingForCurrentCell[]
Off[General::stop];
f::msg = "Message `1`.";
Do[Pause[.5]; Print["Print ", i]; Echo[Row[{"Echo ", i}]];
 Message[f::msg, i]; CellPrint[TextCell["CellPrint " <> ToString[i], "Output"]], {i, 3}]
Style["Final Output", Red, Bold]
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Another solution which works entirely through `CellEpilog` and `CellProlog`, and is applied automatically for all cells of a Notebook (i.e. doesn't require putting a call to any additional function into input cell) can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208203/280).