# How to set the output be generated in a cell different from "Output"

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting, stylesheet, customization

I would have some functions, for instance `Plot`, to generate their output using a different `Cell's` style rather than `"Output"`. The reason is that I'm producing some documents with many images and, for editing reasons, I need to adjust some options of their cell's style.

Unfortunately, I cannot change the `"Output"` style, because other kind of outputs don't have the same formatting as images. Just to make and example, suppose I want all graphics centered in the cell, while other output left aligned. So, I would assign a custom style to the output generate by `Plot`.
Is there any suggestion?

Comment: of course, I don't want to add CellPrint, ExpressionCell, and similar wrapper to the Plot command, I'm looking for something to set at StyleSheet level.

Comment: you could change the cell style of plots post generation. Just click on the cell bracket and select a different style

Comment: Thanks Mike for the reply. That's what I actually do, but working with hundreds of notebooks, each one having many graphics, I would be happy to have a programmatic way to achieve this. However, I guess it's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Graphics output specifically there is a nice approach using [`$DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$DisplayFunction.html):

```
(* create a new output style -- overwrites existing custom style sheet *)
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["altOutput"], TextAlignment -> Center]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
 ]

(* define a display function *)
altOutput[expr_] := CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[expr, "altOutput"]

$DisplayFunction = altOutput;
```

Graphics output in this Notebook will now be centered.  You could also set the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) option for individual plot types independently rather than using the global `$DisplayFunction` parameter.

Comment: +1 Nice. Before they changed the default `DisplayFunction`/graphics typesetting behavior (V5, maybe?), I used the option all the time.  Now I've forgotten that it exists.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks.  The change came in version 6.  You can still load the old graphics subsystem with ``<< Version5`Graphics` `` and reload the new one with ``<< Version6`Graphics` ``

Comment: I'd forgotten about `DisplayFunction` too!

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard, both the solutions you provided are useful for me. Indeed, that one using $DisplayFunction is easy and allows to customize each plot function in a different style, whereas the other one, that using "GeneratedCellStyles" allows to manage different kind of outputs and not only Graphics.

Comment: @bobknight You're welcome, and I'm glad I could help. :-)  It would be nice if there were a more accessible interface for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to change the style used for output with this Front End option:

```
"GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> (* style *)}
```

One can change this style as part of the output formatting routine using [`$PrePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PrePrint.html), like this:

```
defaultOut[] := SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> "Output"}]

altOut[] := SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> "altOutput"}]

output[gr_Graphics] := (altOut[]; gr)
output[other_] := (defaultOut[]; other)

$PrePrint = output;
```

Now (bare) `Graphics` objects will be output with a Cell style of `"altOutput"` rather than `"Output"` yet other expressions will be handled normally.  One could extend `output` to handle an arbitrary number of heads as needed.  (`Graphics` is merely an example here.)

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this for just one output cell? Right now I'm using `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> "Output2"}];` before the output and then `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> "Output"}];` after it to restore future outputs back to normal. But this seems too complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've asked this question (with more details) here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172125/how-can-i-set-the-style-of-one-output-cell-so-it-doesnt-change-after-re-evaluat

Comment: What is especially valuable with `"GeneratedCellStyles"`, it is that this option can be set on the level of individual `Cell`: [an example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207996/280). Is this option (semi-)documented somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it all programmatically you could import the notebook containing the cells with graphics and change the cell style for cells containing graphics:

```
changeStyle[file_String, newStyle_String] := 
  Module[{nb = NotebookOpen[file], nb1},
   nb1 = NotebookGet[nb];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   nb = nb1 /. (p1 : Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[_, ___]], "Output", ___] :> (p1 /. 
         "Output" -> newStyle) );
   NotebookSave[nb, file];
   ];

changeStyle["/pathTo/Untitled.nb", "Text"]
```

To address @MichaelE2 concerns:

```
changeStyle[file_String, newStyle_String] := 
  Module[{nb = NotebookOpen[file], nb1, newfile},
   nb1 = NotebookGet[nb];
   NotebookClose[nb];
   nb = nb1 /. (p1 : 
        Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[_, ___]], "Output", ___] :> (p1 /. 
         "Output" -> newStyle));
   newfile = 
    SystemDialogInput[
     "FileSave", {NotebookDirectory[], {"New File \"*.nb\"" -> {"*.nb"}}}, WindowTitle -> "Saved New Notebook"];
   If[newfile =!= $Canceled && newfile =!= $Failed,
    NotebookSave[nb, newfile]
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: +1. I might save the restyled notebook in a different file or directory, just because I'm a nervous ninny.

Comment: thanks Mike, that seems to be a suitable workaround. I'll try it!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Post.html) to post-process output automatically as it is generated.

For instance, the following outputs anything with the head `Graphics` in a style `"centeredOutput"`, which could be defined in whatever manner one wants.

```
centerGraphics[g_Graphics | g_Graphics3D] := CellPrint@ExpressionCell[g, "centeredOutput"];
centerGraphics[x_] := x;

$Post = centerGraphics
```

One could center the graphics also by wrapping it in `Pane`:

```
centerGraphics[g_Graphics | g_Graphics3D] := Pane[g, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> Full];
```

*Update*: From a suggestion by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), with this definition, formatting the graphics could be handled more gracefully by setting `$PrePrint = centerGraphics` and `$Post =.` (or leave `$Post` unset).  Then the value of `Out` will be the graphics instead of the `Pane`.

***Notes (updated) --***

Any existing graphics would have to be reevaluated.

One should be aware that `$Post` affects the output value.  For example, after executing `Plot`, the head of `%` would be `Cell`, if using the first definition of `centerGraphics`.

One can circumvent `$Post` by wrapping the graphics in a head that does not affect typesetting.  For instance, `Defer@Evaluate@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]` would be printed in a normal `"Output"` cell but the graphics will still be centered.

Because of this, if one wishes to [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Deploy.html) graphics, one might want to add a rule to `centerGraphics` to handle `Deploy`. For example, `centerGraphics[g : Deploy[Graphics[__]] | ...] := ...`

One need not create a special style.  One can set options directly in `ExpressionCell`, such as with this body for the definition of `centerGraphics`:

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[g, "Output", TextAlignment -> Center]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `$Post` rather than `$PrePrint`?  The latter would address your concern regarding `%` unless I'm not thinking clearly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll check it out.  I don't use these processors and forgot about `$PrePrint` -- Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The return value of `$PrePrint` seems to be wrapped in an `"Output"` cell.  So it works for the `Pane` version of `centerGraphics` but not for the cell version.  For that solution, `$PrePrint` seems preferable to me.  I'm stuck for a workaround for the cell method at this point.