# Strange behavior of Print, Do, and merged output cells

Tags: notebooks, cells, output, interactive

The command `Do[Print[i], {i, 1, 3}]` does what you expect: creates 3 output lines of `1`, `2` and `3`, in that order.

If one merges these output cells, then evaluates the original `Do` command, the output is now `3`, then `2`, then `1`. When one deletes the output cells, the regular behavior returns.

It isn't that the `Do` loop is running backwards. When one does "the same thing" with

```
temp = {}
Do[AppendTo[temp, i];
Print[i], {i, 1, 3}];
temp
```

the order of the `Print` command is reversed, but the contents of `temp` are still `{1, 2, 3}`, not `{3, 2, 1}`.

Why does this happen? Does `Print` write to a queue that is sometimes dumped in reverse order?

I am running Mathematica 11.0.0 on Windows 10

Comment: You can see how the printing order is affected by trying with `Do[Pause[1]; Print[i], {i, 1, 3}]`.

Comment: Forgot to add: running Mathematica 11.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: I can reproduce it in M11.3 on macOS.

Comment: Me, too (after Szabolcs explained to me what to do...)

Comment: Related: "[Is it possible to Print expressions in reverse order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4129/280)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason this happens is described in [ref/CellPrint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellPrint.html), in the possible issues section:

> Setting CellAutoOverwrite and GeneratedCell can cause unexpected results:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= CellPrint[Cell["First", "Print", CellAutoOverwrite -> False, 
>    GeneratedCell -> False]];
> "Last"
>
> Out[2]= "Last"
>
> First
> ```

Merging the cells sets these two options:

- it is no longer a generated cell,
- and, theoretically if the user merged the cells, the  user doesn't want them overwritten.

Tricky behavior, but I think it is within the scope of what's documented. A solution to improve the behavior would probably be appreciated, but for now it seems documented and expected.

Answer (score 0):

### Important update

The system doesn't auto-overwrite cells having `Evaluatable->True` even if they have the options `CellAutoOverwrite->True` and `GeneratedCell->True` set (checked with versions 8.0.4, 11.3 and 12.0). AFAIK it isn't documented.

---

### Original post

I would like to add additional references and a discussion to the insightful [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182570/280) by [user6014](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34161/user6014).

From the Documentation page for `OutputAutoOverwrite` (emphasis is mine):

> - With the default setting `OutputAutoOverwrite->True`, the output from a command overwrites any previously existing **output**. Only those output cells that have `CellAutoOverwrite` set to `True` can be overwritten.
> - With the setting `OutputAutoOverwrite->False`, output from each evaluation of a command is printed in the notebook. The output is printed directly after any previously generated **output**.
> - `CellAutoOverwrite` is typically set for cells in `"Output"` style.

From the Documentation page for `GeneratedCell` (emphasis is mine):

> `GeneratedCell` is an option for `Cell` that indicates whether the cell was generated from the kernel.
>
> - The setting for `GeneratedCell` is used to determine which cells should be **considered as** Wolfram Language **output**.

From the Documentation page for `CellAutoOverwrite` (emphasis is mine):

> `CellAutoOverwrite` is an option for `Cell` which specifies whether an **output** cell should be overwritten by new output when the preceding input cell is evaluated.
>
> - Any sequence of cells with `GeneratedCell->True` is assumed to correspond to **output**.
> - With `CellAutoOverwrite->False`, ***new output*** is placed directly ***after the preceding input***, pushing down **pre-existing output**.

So we seemingly have the following vocabulary assumed in the Documentation:

- "output cell" – a `Cell` with option `GeneratedCell -> True` set
- "output" – any sequence of such `Cell`s
- "new output" – output generated during evaluation of the current `EvaluationCell[]`
- "pre-existing output" – output (directly under the `EvaluationCell[]`) generated before beginning of the current evaluation
- `"Output"` – is a name of built-in style which *typically* sets `CellAutoOverwrite -> True` and `GeneratedCell -> True` (we can change it via custom stylesheet)

And the rules which one can deduce from the above observations and the experience:

- If after input cell isn't present a `Cell` with `CellAutoOverwrite -> True`, then *new output* will be placed directly after the input cell pushing down all subjacent pre-existing cells
- If generated new `Cell` has `GeneratedCell -> False`, it won't be considered as a part of *new output*, as well as a part of output at all

From these two rules directly follows that when an input cell generates `Cell`s with both `CellAutoOverwrite -> False` and `GeneratedCell -> False`, they will be printed immediately after it in the reverse order.